# Why is my BuldQualityChecks task failing in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have been using the BuildQualityChecks@8 VSBuild@1 azure pipeline task successfully up until now, when I suddenly started getting the following error:

```
SystemVssConnection exists true
Using IdentifierJobResolver
Validating code coverage policy...
Successfully read code coverage data from build.
Total lines: 0
Covered lines: 0
Code Coverage (%): 0
[ERROR] The code coverage value (0%, 0 lines) is lower than the minimum value (19%)!
```

I also noticed that my PublishBuildArtifacts@1 task (executed after BuildQualityChecks) is failing because it can't find the path to my c# code:

```
##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: C:\a\1\s\App.Utils.cs\Utility\bin\x64\Release
```

This is my pipeline task:

```
- task: mspremier.BuildQualityChecks.QualityChecks-task.BuildQualityChecks@8
  displayName: 'Check build quality'
  inputs:
    checkCoverage: true
    coverageFailOption: fixed
    coverageType: lines
    coverageThreshold: 0
    buildConfiguration: Test
    buildPlatform: x86
```

I set the coverageThreshold to 0 for now in order to get a working build, but I would love to get to the root of the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline fails for you most likely due to the fact that you're running it with 0 covered lines and 0 total lines.

There is an option, from [the available list of options viewed on the VS marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks), to treat 0% coverage as 100%. This is turned off by default, so it might solve your problem.

This means that you should put this option into your task:

```
 treat0of0as100: false
```